# mysql/php loop with multiple forms or just one?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, forms, loops

i've looked around and did no find an answer to a question that has been bugging me for quite some time.
let's say i have a mysql table with tasks. in php i loop through all the records and display them. each row should have buttons e.g. "done", "delete", etc. which will trigger an action (preferably with ajax).

now the question is, should i do this with multiple forms or just with one? is there a best practice for that? are there considerable advantages/disadvantages for each of the options?

i did search on this site, so my apologies in advance, should i have missed a post explaining just that.

thanks a lot in advance

Comment: what would be the advantage in using multiple forms ? (i usually use 1 form only for similar things)

Comment: Apologies or not, read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. This question is too broad to answer.

Comment: No need for any forms if this is being handled by javascript (ajax). Do it however you like but be consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would write it.  I don't see the need for forms.  I think forms might slightly over complicate the process.

```
<ul>
    <li mysqlId="0">Name <button class="done">Done</button> <button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
    <li mysqlId="1">Name <button class="done">Done</button> <button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
</ul>

<script>
    $(".done").click(function () {
        mysqlId = $(this).parents("li:first").attr("mysqlId");
        $.post(/* ajax magic */);
    });

    $(".delete").click(function () {
        mysqlId = $(this).parents("li:first").attr("mysqlId");
        $.post(/* ajax magic */);
    });
</script>
```